# ImageButton.getWidth() and getHeight() returns 0

Tags: android

Currently in my android app, my ImageButton `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` returns 0. Upon searching the forums, I realized that this is because the Layout/View hasn't been done/finalized by the OS, hence returning 0. Thus, they recommend using the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to solve this issue. However, the button is created in a Fragment, which has an `onCreateView()` method which returns the View of the fragment. So how do I attach this Listener in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly in the same way. You can do it in `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated`. The important part is that it has to be after you `inflate` your layout:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    final View measuredView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.measured_view);
    measuredView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int width = measuredView.getWidth();
            int height = measuredView.getHeight();
            if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    measuredView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    measuredView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
                //DO SOMETHING WITH NON-ZERO DIMENSIONS
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opintion,after `setContentView(..)` method execute,you can get height and width